# Join two tables so foreign key column data (integer) changes to text data from parent table (concerned column in parent table is not primary key)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am a beginner with SQLite, and I am still a little unfamiliar with joining tables (and the limitations therein). I would like to know how to join 2 tables so that the column data in Table B (several columns) changes to reflect data from Table A.

```
CREATE TABLE "A" (
      "person_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      "person_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
      "email"   TEXT NOT NULL
);

    CREATE TABLE "B" (
          "company_id"  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          "company_name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
          "contact_one" INTEGER NOT NULL,
          "contact_two" INTEGER,
          "contact_three"   INTEGER,
          FOREIGN KEY("contact_one") REFERENCES "A"("person_id") ON DELETE SET NULL
          FOREIGN KEY("contact_two") REFERENCES "A"("person_id") ON DELETE SET NULL
          FOREIGN KEY("contact_three") REFERENCES "A"("person_id") ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

How do I write a query so that the resulting table shows columns "company_name", "contact_one", "contact_two" and "contact_three" BUT with the contact tables showing the contact name rather than the integer (as it would appear in Table B).

See below an image representing Tables A and B and the desired output of SQLite query:

[image: Tables A and B and the desired output of SQLite query]

When I do a left join, the query succeeds only for a single contact column.

```
SELECT B.company_name, A.person_name
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON B.contact_one = A.person_id
```

I tried to add an "OR" to the query (I know "AND" will not work), but I get an "ambiguous column name: A.person_name" error when I try to run the query:

```
SELECT B.company_name, A.person_name
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON B.contact_one = A.person_id
OR LEFT JOIN A ON B.contact_two = A.person_id
OR LEFT JOIN A ON B.contact_three = A.person_id
```

How do I write the query so that I can get contact_two and contact_three also in the resulting table, with all three contacts' names displayed?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no need for images here. Use tabular text or in case of sample data `INSERT INTO` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table A 3 times like this:

```
SELECT B.company_name, 
  a1.person_name name1,
  a2.person_name name2,
  a3.person_name name3
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A a1 ON B.contact_one = a1.person_id
LEFT JOIN A a2 ON B.contact_two = a2.person_id
LEFT JOIN A a3 ON B.contact_three = a3.person_id
```